# CSS: flexbox horizontal overflow

Tags: css, flexbox, horizontal-scrolling, stretched

How is it possible to let children items of a flexbox container **not stretch** but **overflow horizontally**? So that you can either scroll with overflow-x or cut the content on the right side.

[image]

My experiments ended with horizontally stretched items although they have a fixed width.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please show some code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the flex-container has `flex-wrap:no-wrap` (default), then setting it to `overflow:auto;` and  the flex-items to `flex: 0 0 100%` (or whatever your desired width instead of 100%) should be enough.

```css
section{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

div{
  background-color:chartreuse;
  height:2rem;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
</section>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif you're totally right, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Wow, very interesting why it works only with `flex-shrink: 0;`. Spent some time until found your answer. Thnk you!